# Swift: AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue returns kAXErrorSuccess but got nil pointer

Tags: cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite

please excuse me for my bad English! I'm trying to get the focused application in Mac OS X. The code below works fine when running in XCode 6.1.1:

```
func getFocusedApp() -> AXUIElementRef? {
    let systemWideElement : AXUIElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide().takeRetainedValue()
    let kAXFocusedApplication : CFString! = "AXFocusedApplication"
    var focusedElementPtr : Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
    var error : AXError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedApplication, &focusedElementPtr)
    if let ue = focusedElementPtr {
        return ue.takeUnretainedValue() as AXUIElementRef
    }
    else {
        printError(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

in which *printError* is obviously a function to print out the error. However when I archive the app to put into Applications folder of Yosemite, *focusedElementPtr* is always nil while *error == AXError(kAXErrorSuccess)* (accessibility enabled, it passes the *AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions* test). I couldn't figure out what's wrong. So it would be nice if someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: I guessed it was related to memory management, so I changed the code to:

```
func getFocusedApp() -> AXUIElementRef? {
    var output: AXUIElementRef? = nil
    let systemWideElement : AXUIElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide().takeRetainedValue()
    let kAXFocusedApplication : CFString! = "AXFocusedApplication"
    var focusedElementPtr : UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<AnyObject>?> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<AnyObject>?>.alloc(1)
    var error : AXError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedApplication, focusedElementPtr)
    if let ue = focusedElementPtr.memory {
        output = ue.takeUnretainedValue() as AXUIElementRef
    }
    else {
        printError(error)
    }
    focusedElementPtr.dealloc(1)
    return output
}
```

It may not be the best solution but now the app runs as expected :) I'm sorry if I've wasted someone's time!

Comment: Hey, did you resolve an issue with this function? I want to use it but this version not work.